# NetSuite Item Receipt Calculate Total Amount

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

In NetSuite, I need to calculate total amount (ie line item qty x line item rate) in the item receipt. This is unavailable in standard functionalities so scripting is needed.

Below is the client side script - which is working fine if we are manually ticking the line items. However, it gets distorted once we use the mark all or unmark all button in the item receipt because unfortunately, these buttons do not trigger client scripts. I am thinking of using a recalculate button to correct the amounts before user saves the transaction. Any ideas?

I also tried workflow action script but the recalc button appears to be greyed out when first creating/editing the transaction. Thanks so much.

```
function fieldChng() {
  var qty = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity');
  var rate = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'rate');
  var total = qty * rate;
  nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_ir_line_item_amount', total.toFixed(2), false);
  //'custcol_ir_line_item_amount' is the internal id of Custom Transaction Line Field

}
function updateTotalAmount(type, name) {
  // initialize variable for total amount
  var totalAmount = 0;

  // count number of lines in 'item' sublist
  var itemCount = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');

  // for each line in the 'item' sublist, add value in amount column to
  // the total amount variable
  for (var i = 1; i <= itemCount; i++) {
    lineLevelAmount = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_ir_line_item_amount', i)
    if (lineLevelAmount != '' && lineLevelAmount != null) {
      totalAmount += parseFloat(lineLevelAmount);
    }
  }

  // assuming custbody_ir_total_amount is the custom body field for the total
  // amount, change its value based the value from the computation above
  nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody_ir_total_amount', totalAmount.toFixed(2), false);
}
```

Comment: You could use the `saveRecord()` entry point in your client script to re-calculate all of the line items when the user clicks the `Save` button.

Answer (score 0):

As Mike said it's better to do this on "save" but there's always the option to hijack the "Mark All" button and have this trigger your script. It's less NetSuite approved but it works just as fine.